# What is the default user of instructions in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I have done an experiment to check this out. The following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic                                

RUN echo $UID > a.out && echo "hello" > a.out     
RUN useradd -m user      
RUN echo $UID > b.out                             

USER user
```

The result of a.out and b.out is shown below.

```
user@39370ee77a16:/$ cat a.out
hello
user@39370ee77a16:/$ cat b.out
```

My question is:

1. Is root the default user?
2. Why $UID in Dockerfile shows nothing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What has not been fully addressed in other answers (so far) is your second question:

> Why $UID in Dockerfile shows nothing?

`$UID` is a bash internal variable. When the image is created from the dockerfile, bash is not used, so `$UID` is not defined, hence using it returns an empty string.

To make this answer complete, even if it has already been answered:

> Is root the default user?

That depends on how the image in the `FROM` statement was setup.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to docker. Could you tell me when is $UID defined? As soon as bash is used?

Comment: Yes. It's an internal variable in bash and it's set up as soon as bash starts.

Answer (score 5):

It depend upon the base image, but in you case the default user is root. you can verify from the [base image](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/7f7bea7f1fb44b7394681f5a0dabb7acab96f875/bionic/Dockerfile) or inside Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic 
RUN whoami
```

In your case, you see `hello` because you override the content, try with

```
RUN echo $UID >> a.out && echo "hello" >> a.out
```

You can change user using

```
USER my_user
```